# Proper 404 handling by server with vue-router in history mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When using history mode in vue-router the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) is suggesting a pretty dodgy way to get around some of the limitations it has.It suggests a server-side configuration that catches all URLs that *could* be a client-side route and rewriting to root (/) so the client-side app is delivered. And then another catch-all route to a 404 component in the client-side router if no routes match.

Problem is, this will mean your server is returning 200 OK status codes to crawlers/indexers for basically every URL, specifically ones that don’t technically exist.

My thoughts so far:

- Use IIS `<rewriteMap>` to list the valid client-side route patterns I have and use that for matches instead of a catch-all on everything not a file/dir.

  - Problem: pain to manage in tandem with client-side routes.
- Routes defined in server config and handed to client-side router via an api endpoint for registration

  - Problem: setting up an API when you just want to host a static app is a pain.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi OP, any luck on this we're sitting with the same issue getting 200 status on 404's and the pages are being cached as they are not seen as 404s.

Comment: Posted at the time in the vue forum too and got no response. I ended up leaving it on my app as it wasn't really a production site so never followed through on an answer. Only thing I can suggest is trying one of my suggestions. Sorry!

Comment: Hitting an API for available routes on load will add overhead/loading time. The search continues :) Thanks

Comment: I think your best bet is to remove the catch-all route client-side, and then have your server actually send back the 404. To do this means maintaining a list of valid URLs for the app on whatever server stack you use and 404ing anything you don't recognise. Fairly easy with IIS Rewrite, but depends what stack you're on. That means a search engine hitting for the first time will be rejected by your server.

Comment: Any update on this one? I am still having same problems.

Comment: Unfortunately not @YigitAlparslan, but I'd recommend having a list of urls you support on your server that you verify on a server-side hit and if not in that list, write back a 404. Perhaps with nginx or IISRewrite, whatever you've got in place.